# Validating RequestBody object not checking for NotNull

Tags: java, json, spring, spring-mvc, jackson

I am using Spring `@RequestBody` and JacksonMapper to handle the payload for a  have a REST call. My `RestController` class like this:

```
@RequestMapping(value="/mobile/device", method=RequestMethod.PUT, consumes={MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE}, produces=MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)
public ResponseEntity<Object> flagDevice (@Valid @RequestBody List<DeviceInfo> deviceInfoList) {
    ...code here...
}
```

My (simplified for this example) `DeviceInfo` class looks like this:

```
@Entity
@JsonIgnoreProperties(ignoreUnknown=true)
public class DeviceInfo implements Serializable {

    @Id 
    @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @JsonIgnore
    private long id;

    @NotNull(message="Must have valid activityDate parameter.")
    @Past
    private ZonedDateTime activityDate;

    @JsonProperty("mobile-data")
    @NotNull(message="Must have an associated MobileDeviceData object.")
    private MobileDeviceData mobileDeviceData;
}
```

I am using the Hibernate validator `org.hibernate:hibernate-validator:5.2.2.Final`. To me it seems if I don't pass the activityDate parameter or the nested mobileDeviceData object in my JSON, then after deserializing it should throw an exception. However these values go through as null just fine. What am I doing wrong?

**UPDATE**

After doing some testing I found that `@Valid` and `@Validated` will only validate the List and not the Objects it contains. I got this to work by adding this `@Bean` to my Application class:

```
@Bean
public LocalValidatorFactoryBean localValidatorFactoryBean() {
    return new LocalValidatorFactoryBean();
}
```

and then injecting that into my `DeviceInfo` class. I was then able to loop through the List and validate with

```
for (DeviceInfo deviceInfo : deviceInfoList) {
    Set<ConstraintViolation<DeviceInfo>> violationSet = localValidatorFactory.validate(deviceInfo);
}
```

and then check the returning Set for errors. This is not idea and would like a way to tell Spring to validate the Objects in the List and not the List itself.

Comment: What is a valid List by your definition?

Comment: Should work afaik. Are the other checks done correctly?

Comment: can you please try @validated instead of AT valid

Comment: I tried that. Didnt work either. Same result.

Comment: I have a similar issue where nested objects are not validated. I have a one-to-many relationship in which content I'd like to have validated as well. The requestbody object is checked is checked fine just as the OP described.